# Websocket VB Server large data sending

Tags: vb.net, websocket

Iam using the SendMessage for sending data to clients. If the byte length is bigger than 125 this Sub not working. If the byte length is smaller then 125 everything ok. for example byte length is 138 script is not working
Here is the code;

```
Sub SendMessage(sck As Socket, message As String)
    Dim rawData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)
    Dim frameCount = 0
    Dim frame(10) As Byte
    frame(0) = CByte(129)
    Console.WriteLine("bukar:" & rawData.Length)
    If rawData.Length <= 125 Then
        frame(1) = CByte(rawData.Length + 1)
        frameCount = 2
    ElseIf rawData.Length >= 126 AndAlso rawData.Length <= 65535 Then
        frame(1) = CByte(126)
        Dim len = CByte(rawData.Length + 1)
        frame(2) = CByte(((len >> 8) & CByte(255)))
        frame(3) = CByte((len & CByte(255)))
        frameCount = 4
    Else
        frame(1) = CByte(127)
        Dim len = CByte(rawData.Length + 1)
        frame(2) = CByte(((len >> 56) & CByte(255)))
        frame(3) = CByte(((len >> 48) & CByte(255)))
        frame(4) = CByte(((len >> 40) & CByte(255)))
        frame(5) = CByte(((len >> 32) & CByte(255)))
        frame(6) = CByte(((len >> 24) & CByte(255)))
        frame(7) = CByte(((len >> 16) & CByte(255)))
        frame(8) = CByte(((len >> 8) & CByte(255)))
        frame(9) = CByte((len & CByte(255)))
        frameCount = 10
    End If
    Dim bLength = frameCount + rawData.Length
    ' Console.WriteLine(frameCount)
    'Console.WriteLine(rawData.Length)
    Dim reply(bLength) As Byte

    Dim bLim = 0
    For i = 0 To frameCount - 1
        '  Console.WriteLine(bLim)
        reply(bLim) = frame(i)
        bLim += 1
    Next

    For i = 0 To rawData.Length - 1
        '   Console.WriteLine(bLim)
        reply(bLim) = rawData(i)
        bLim += 1
    Next
    'For i = 0 To reply.Length - 1
    'Console.WriteLine("Byte: " & reply(i))
    'Console.WriteLine("Char: " & CByte(reply(i)))
    'Next
    sck.Send(reply, reply.Length, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know much about VB, but I know a bit about WebSockets.

A frame header for a complete message of 138 bytes should be 4 bytes:

```
0 - 129
1 - 126
2 - 0
3 - 138
```

Check if your code is producing that header.

I developed a [WebSocket server connector for .NET/Mono](http://vtortola.github.io/WebSocketListener/), check the source code in GitHub, it may solve you some issues. Not to mention you can use the library from VB as well.

Cheers.